# Can vim warn on a tabpagemax overflow?

Tags: vim, vi

If I open a collection of files in vim tabs using a glob pattern, I'd like to be warned if the number of files matching the pattern exceeds the value of `tabpagemax`. For example, if the following,

```
$ vi -p `find . -type f -name "*.tex"`
```

matches more files than `tabpagemax`, only `tabpagemax` tabbed documents are opened. I'd like a warning or error in this case. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not finding any method where `vim` can emit a warning when the `tabpagemax` is exceeded, so the next best thing is to check, prior to running `vim`.

#### Potential solution

Here we're running the find first, storing the results in a variable, `$tfiles`. We then only invoke `vim -p` if the number of files we've found is less than or equal to the `$guard` value, 20.

```
$ guard=20
$ tfiles=$(find . -type f -name "*.tex")
$ [ $(echo $tfiles | wc -w) -le $guard ] && vim -p $tfiles || echo "too many"
```

This can be converted to a oneliner like so:

```
$ guard=20; \
tfiles=$(find . -type f -name "*.tex"); \
[ $(echo $tfiles | wc -w) -le $guard ] && vim -p $tfiles || echo "too many"
```

#### Example

When we have more than say 3 files returned we'll get this type of experience:

```
$ guard=3; \
  tfiles=$(find . -type f -name "*.txt"); \
  [ $(echo $tfiles | wc -w) -le $guard ] && vim -p $tfiles || echo "too many"
too many
```

If we have less then 3 files, they'll be opened up in `vim` in separate tabs.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I had thought of that, but it's handy to see it worked through. I guess this could then also be wrapped up in a vimrc script; use `tabpagemax` etc.

Comment: @user7543 - correct you could get fancy and get the `tabpagemax` in .vimrc, and have the `$guard` parse the file to get that setting. `guard=$(grep tabpagemax ~/.vimrc | cut -d"=" -f2)`.